# How to make both batsmen centuries in cricket match?

Tags: logical-deduction, situation, sports

This puzzle asked me to in the interview.

> In a Cricket match, **Two batsmen** are on **92(on strike)** and **99** runs respectively. **Three balls**
>   remaining and both batsmen make 100 and win the match.

**Note:**

> - No extra ball or run allowed(wide, no ball, over throw etc).
> - Last wicket on crease.
> - both batsmen need complete 100. No more than 100 run.

**How is it possible?**

Comment: It's so easy. Batsmen on strike hit SIX (1st Ball), 2nd ball 2 runs + 1 overthrow (Now Batmen on strike finish 100 and reached at Non-strike end), then Batsmen 2 came on strike hit 1 run in 3rd ball (complete 100)

Comment: No over throw run allowed

Comment: Yeah That's what I mention in above comment, in 2 balls (6+2) 8 for Batsmen-1 can reach 100. But after ball 2, Batsmen-1 on non strike because of Overthrow and final ball Batsmen-2 came on strike and hit 1 run (complete 100)

Comment: Were you interviewing for a cricket commentary position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st ball:**

> Striker **batsman(92)** hits the ball for 3 run but when he runs he made **1 run short** and fielder throw the ball. By this he got 2 run(who reached on 94) and reached at non-striker's end.

**2nd ball:**

> Non-striker batsman reached at striker's end and he made **1 run** and completed his **100** and reached at non-striker's end.

**3rd ball:**

> The Non-Stricker batsman reached at the striker's end and he **hits six** off the last ball and completed his **100**.

Comment: Um.. you self-answered far too soon IMO. Only 50 views so far.

Comment: @Sid Then, Can I delete my answer?

Comment: This answer is more complicated than mine; what is its advantage over mine? (E.g., does mine not work for some subtle reason?)

Answer (score 3):

So far as I am aware,

> it is not *illegal* or *impossible* for a batsman to score any number of runs while waiting for the fielders to get their act together; it's just very unusual for the number to be large.

So, e.g., perhaps

> batsman 1 scores 7, leaving batsman 2 facing the bowler;
>  batsman 2 scores 1, leaving batsman 1 facing the bowler;
>  batsman 1 scores 1.

Of course

> we can redistribute batsman 1's runs, provided the first number is odd; perhaps 3+4 is more realistic.

Comment: Yep - [totally possible and has happened](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqswGyXGzlg) (the 7 runs that is)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to running five (or seven) - a fielder has brought a helmet on to the pitch and for the time being has taken it off and left it behind the wicket-keeper's position. On the first ball, the ball strikes the helmet on the way to the boundary. This scores an automatic 5. The batsman on strike then makes three on the next ball, leaving the other batsman at the right end to score a single on the last ball.